# Pipes between Windows and Linux Apps

Tags: c#, linux, pipe, named-pipes, data-transfer

If I have a Windows and a Linux machines on the same LAN, can I use (named) pipes to talk between the two?

I am specifically thinking of using `System.IO.Pipes` namespace in C# or VB.NET on the Windows side.

Comment: Named pipes are rarely used for inter-machine communication, why are you using them instead of TCP?

Comment: I am just in the process of learning more about pipes. Windows allows you to use pipes between Windows machines on the same LAN. Is TCP a better fit for inter-machine comms?

Answer (score 2):

Named pipes alone cannot accomplish this over IP. The simplest solution is that you create a named pipe on each machine and use netcat (`nc` in Linux) to send information between the pipes.

I don't know how that works in Windows, but I can give an example of doing it in Linux (rather, any modern Unix), and there's probably some easy way to do adapt this for Windows:

`machinea` wants to talk to `machineb`. A opens named pipe at `/tmp/mypipe` that some program writes to. B opens named pipe at `/tmp/mypipe` that some program reads from. B runs `nc -l 9000 > /tmp/mypipe` to listen for TCP/IP connections on port 9000 and write the output to the named pipe. A runs `cat /tmp/mypipe | nc machineb 9000` to read from its named pipe and pipe the read data to netcat to send it to machine B. Of course, the programs running on A and B don't "care" whether the pipe information is going over TCP/IP; netcat handles that, and they just talk to their named pipes, however they're supposed to do that.

You may need to fiddle with the order in which you open the named pipes, open the programs that read/write to/from them, and run the netcat commands. I'm answering this from memory.

Answer (score 0):

UNIX Named pipes are **NEVER** used for intermachine communication.  A named pipe is a special inode in the filesystem (that makes it have a name like any other file) One process calls **open(2)** for reading or writing (normally one process opens it for reading and the other for writting) and other process connect to it via the named FIFO.  The named fifos are implemented specially in the kernel, as when the FIFO is empty, a process reading from it will be blocked waiting for it to have data.  Also, when a process fills up the FIFO (they have limited capacity, as they use a small amount of blocks from the inode pointers --- only the direct blocks)  it's blocked on writting until some reader empties the fifo data.

As one file in the filesystem is only visible in the server hosting it, it has no network visibility, and cannot be used as a network communications mechanism.

For network communication you have the **socket(2)** (and friends) interface.  There exists also what is called *Unix domain sockets*, which are sockets in the sense of being bidirectional (and you have to connect them, also) but are *only for local use*, mainly because they don't use the full TCP/IP stack to comunicate one end to the other.  They appear like this (with a `p` in the first mode position) in the **ls(1)** listings:

```
luis@asus-luis:/run$ ll hogsuspend 
prw------- 1 root root 0 ago 10 16:54 hogsuspend
```

and unix sockets do it so:

```
luis@asus-luis:/run$ ll /dev/gpmctl 
srwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 ago 10 16:54 /dev/gpmctl
```

(with an `s`)

---

@mcu, to be able to use some communication means between machines in a network you need to use network compatible technology.  Pipes were first invented in unix environments, and didn't use at all networking capabilities, and that has been true since then, and Microsoft adapted the term to something they use to intercommunicate their machines.  Today all the communication infrastructure in Windows uses partly or completely TCP/IP stack.  This means that named pipes, when it is the case to use network resources, somehow, should use some kind of process making a gateway to TCP/IP resources.  In that case, probably a TCP socket (if you want to maintain reliability) will be used to make the interconnection between machines.  I don't know actually the mechanism behind Windows named pipes or how the interoperate with the network.  I'll find some information for you and try to extend my explanation to be useful for you.  UNIX named pipes appear in the system's filesystem and so, are not visible (and in case they are, using NFS or some other network capable remote filesystem access, don't give transparent acces to the remote resources as if they were a local resource)

The term unix named pipe was coined to represent an interprocess communication object used to provide half-duplex, transparent comunication between two processes.  The name was coined from water pipes, that were used to transfer continously water(data) between two points in a serialized, reliable way.

Windows borrowed the concept and implemented some SOCKET like object, but with a NetBios based naming structure.  This means that if you use Windows on top of TCP/IP stack (this is NetBios runs using TCP/IP sockets, which can be not the case) you still need some way (this is provided as a NetBios service) to map a pipe name (something in the form `\\machine\pipe_name` following Netbios naming, into a host ip/address and a port number) through a NetBios call (this can be available if you install on linux/unix some software like Samba) or you implement that service yourself on top of TCP/IP.

Unix pipes exist since the beginnings of unix, and probably named pipes were introduce around year 1975 or 1978 (still two years to wait for MS-DOS to be born, and more to see Microsoft Windows living)

The concept named pipe used in Windows is complete different thing that as it is used in unix (or linux) and so, you should consider using a Linux socket for the thing.  But in order to communicate with a Windows named pipe, you need to still know how windows maps named pipes into tcp/ip sockets --- and that only, which is normally the case, that Windows is using its SMB sockets (IMHO better name than pipes, as they represent a point to connect, and not the full connection channel, despite what Microsoft can think)---

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590%28VS.85%29.aspx _Named pipes can be used to provide communication between processes on the same computer or between processes on different computers across a network._

Comment: @mcu, Probably that's right, but it doesn't invalidate my response.  Don't see a reason to invalidate it that way.  Named pipes to communicate internetwork nodes require some means of ensuring the communication is available, so I cannot imagine the easy `open`, `read`, `write` and `close` semantics of plain pipes, without far more kernel support from the OS.  Either case, the question was **...between windows/linux machines**, meaning interoperate.  Have you tried that named pipes of windows to connect to a named pipe of linux?  How they should do that if linux doesn't support it?

Comment: *Named pipes are NEVER used for intermachine communication*. This article begs to differ: "They can be used to pass data between processes running on the same machine, or between processes on different machines connected via a network.", see: https://takethenotes.com/how-does-a-named-pipe-fifo-work-in-linux/

Comment: @PaulJurczak, I'm afraid named pipes cannot be used for network comunications.  That article can be wrong.  Sockets are used for that, indeed.  A named pipe is accessable by it's name in the local filesystem, so it will be difficult to access it on a network filesystem.  You mean probably sockets.  I'm a unix developer since 1987, and I know what I'm talking about, a named pipe is just a pipe with a name in the filesystem.  You cannot use it for more than to pass data to another process in the same system.  No kernel support for more.

Comment: Some systems (e.g. BSD) use sockets to implement named pipes.  Probably some extension of BSD can use them to pass information from system to system.  Or windows has some other thing that they call pipes, but unix named pipes are only for local comms.

Comment: @PaulJurczak, I'm afraid you (and me) are right.  Microsoft uses the name named pipe to identify a completely different (and network) capable kind of object than UNIX named pipes.  This object has it's place in the NetBios protocol, running on top of TCP/IP and so, can handle interconnections between processes in different Windows nodes.  But unix named pipes that where invented in the eighties, and the name was borrowed by Microsoft from the use they did in unix, is a completely different object.  This makes unix named pipes and Windows named pipes no interoperable, and so, the answer I...

Comment: give is correct.  Sorry if you don't agree... but you will never be able to connect a Windows named pipe (the equivalent to a TCP/IP socket, and probably the final media used to interconnect Windows named pipes) requires to implement part of the windows exclusive NetBios protocol (over TCP/IP, or use Samba services) to be interoperable with unix.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by flaming. I responded to your statement, which you edited since. The statement seemed to be incorrect, because it wasn't limited to "interoperability between Windows named pipes and Linux". I made my comment in the course of my research to solve a design problem I have. No ill will towards you, just dealing with the facts. Since you edited your post and we left a long comment trail, I'm removing the downvote.